# Why multi-threaded code runs slower on faster machines?

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduling

Consider following c++ code:

```
#include "threadpool.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int loop_size;

void process(int num) {
    double x = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < loop_size; ++i) {
        x += 0.0001;
        sum += sin(x) / cos(x) + cos(x) * cos(x);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << argv[0] << " [thread_pool_size] [threads] [sleep_time]" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    thread_pool* pool = nullptr;
    int th_count = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    if(th_count != 0) {
        pool = new thread_pool(th_count);
    }
    loop_size = std::stoi(argv[3]);
    int max = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    auto then = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::list<std::thread> ths;
    if(th_count == 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
            ths.emplace_back(&process, i);
        }
        for(std::thread& t : ths) {
            t.join();
        }
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
            pool->enqueue(std::bind(&process, i));
        }
        delete pool;
    }
    int diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - then).count();
    std::cerr << "Time: " << diff << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And `"threadpool.hpp"` is modified version of [this github repo](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h)  and it is available [here](https://gist.github.com/soroush/d85a2a4d7d84dbc06b38b61e030ac489)

I compiled above code on my machine (Corei7-6700) and a 88-core server (2x Xeon E5-2696 v4). The results I can't explain.

This is how I run the code:

```
tp <threadpool size> <number of threads> <iterations>
```

The very same code runs slower on faster machines! I have 8 cores on my local machine and 88 cores on remote server and these are results: (last two columns indicate average time to complete in milliseconds on each machine)

```
+============+=========+============+=============+====================+
| Threadpool | Threads | Iterations | Corei7-6700 | 2x Xeon E5-2696 v4 |
+============+=========+============+=============+====================+
|        100 |  100000 |       1000 |        1300 |               6000 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|       1000 |  100000 |       1000 |        1400 |               5000 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|      10000 |  100000 |       1000 |        1470 |               3400 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

It seems having more cores makes the code run slower. So I reduced CPU affinity on server ([taskset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)) to 8 cores and run the code again:

```
taskset 0-7 tp <threadpool size> <number of threads> <iterations>
```

This is the new data:

```
+============+=========+============+=============+====================+
| Threadpool | Threads | Iterations | Corei7-6700 | 2x Xeon E5-2696 v4 |
+============+=========+============+=============+====================+
|        100 |  100000 |       1000 |        1300 |                900 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|       1000 |  100000 |       1000 |        1400 |               1000 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|      10000 |  100000 |       1000 |        1470 |               1070 |
+------------+---------+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

I have tested the same code on a 32-core Xeon and a 22-core old Xeon machine, and the pattern is similar: Having less cores, makes the multi-threaded code run faster. But why?

IMPORTANT NOTE: This is an effort to solve my original problem here:

[Why having more and faster cores makes my multithreaded software slower?](https://serverfault.com/questions/919552/why-having-more-and-faster-cores-makes-my-multithreaded-software-slower)

Notes:

1. The operating system and compilers are same on all machines: debian 9.0 amd64 running kernel 4.0.9-3, 6.3.0 20170516
2. No additional flasg, default optimization: `g++ ./threadpool.cpp -o ./tp -lpthread`

Comment: What is the point of measuring speed of unoptimized program?

Comment: Your "process" seems to be code the compiler can completely optimise away.

Comment: @NeilButterworth probably that's why optimization is not used

Comment: Have you profiled this example?

Comment: Please, run the code with `th_count=0`, that might clarify a lot.

Comment: @Slava The point is to understand the behavior of scheduling in kernel. This is not a real program of course.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes. Except it is not optimized away (perf shows actual sin and cos running in libc)

Comment: @Arcinde Yes, I have done that. In the user space everything looks normal. on the kernel side `native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath` takes ~50% of load on many-core systems.

Comment: What happens when you vary the number of number of iterations (`loop_size`)? I have no basis for guessing the cost of a single task relative to the synchronization overhead.

Comment: Try making the individual threads run for much longer (maybe three to four orders of magnitude), and start correspondingly fewer of them.  I have a suspicion that the slowdown could be due to starting a significant number of threads on different physical processors.

Comment: Oh, and 2x Xeon is going to be NUMA, which means you're thrashing that mutex across the QPI. See what happens if you `numactl -m 0 -N 0` (or similar) to limit your threads to a single physical socket and it's attached memory

Comment: And yeah, ideally the number of threads is similar to the number of cores, otherwise you're just spending extra time in the scheduler for no benefit.

Comment: @Useless I will try that and come back tommorow.

Comment: @sorush-r why you do not pass `loop_size` to a function, but use global var (which makes your program basically illegal) and pass useless value instead?

Comment: [Relevant discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11018294) on @Useless point

Comment: So basically you measured that mutex lock/unlock is more expensive on multicore machine, why does it surprise you  and how this code is relevant? Just put empty functions and you probably get similar results.

Comment: It's interesting. A thread pool size of 100 shouldn't be taxing the scheduler, and strangely increasing the thread pool size makes it faster. Maybe you could consider trying another, more advanced thread pool implementation and see if it helps.

Comment: @Arcinde actual work is too small and time spent here is mostly on syncs, not calculations. So I doubt any thread pool implementation would help here.

Comment: Amdahl's Law, perhaps.

Comment: One way to ensure that the code of `process` is not optimized away would be to have a shared variable `atomic<double> sumGlobal(0);` to which every local `sum` is added, and then print `sumGlobal` at the end, in the main thread. Then, you can redo your measurements (I would also recommend turning optimizations on : `O2` or `O3` and maybe `NDEBUG`)

Comment: @Slava How is reading a global from multiple threads illegal when its value is set before any of those threads are created and it never changes?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how do you know that its value is actually flushed from register to cache, from cache to memory and from memory to cache of another CPU before other threads start? Who guarantees that?

Comment: @Slava The threading standard that he's using does. In this case, he's using C++'s `std::thread` threads, and they provide a guarantee that a primitive value that is written to prior to the creation of a thread can be read in that thread so long as another thread cannot modify it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you point to documentation for such guarantee? Anyway if you look into code thread pool is actually created before value is assigned to `loop_size`

Comment: @Slava That makes it even easier. Then the guarantee comes from the dispatch lock, which is a `std::mutex`. Mutexes would be totally useless if they didn't guarantee that a thread that holds a mutex after another thread releases it isn't guaranteed to see everything the first thread did before it released the mutex! (The pattern is: Set value, acquire mutex to queue work, acquire mutex to dequeue work, access value. So the mutex guarantees visibility.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no it does not make it easier :( If you look into source https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h mutex is used in line 77 to sync access to internal `stop` variable, and is not acquired when thread func is actually called. Sorry...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mean line 74, line 77 is synchronized access to `stop` variable. Actually this mutex lock most probably is the reason for this slowness - all cores access it after short execution time

Comment: @Slava The initial thread sets the global variable and then queues work units, acquiring the mutex to do it. No thread can do a work unit without first removing it from the queue, also under the protection of the mutex. So the mutex assures memory visibility of `loop_size`. Were this not so, mutexes would be unusable. In fact, the thread pool would be horribly broken if it didn't guarantee a thread that started work on something couldn't see changes made prior to the work unit being queued -- how could you pass work to threads without that guarantee?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I pointed you to source where it is clear that mutex is not aquired before thread function accesses variable `loop_size`. I disagree that such thread pool would be broken, as it is thread function implementer job to properly sync access to shared resources. Anyway in this case access to `loop_size` is not protected by mutex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176290/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-slava).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz got it, yes it was protected by mutex, you are right.

Answer (score 6):

You are enqueueing a ton of workers into the thread pool which take very little time to execute. Consequently you are bottlenecked by the implementation of the thread pool (*not* the actual work), specifically the way its mutex handles contention. I tried replacing `thread_pool` with [`folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/executors/CPUThreadPoolExecutor.h), which kind of helped:

```
thread_pool version:
2180 ms | thread_pool_size=100   num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-23
2270 ms | thread_pool_size=1000  num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-23
2400 ms | thread_pool_size=10000 num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-23
 530 ms | thread_pool_size=100   num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-7
1930 ms | thread_pool_size=1000  num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-7
2300 ms | thread_pool_size=10000 num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-7
folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor version:
 830 ms | thread_pool_size=100   num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-23
 780 ms | thread_pool_size=1000  num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-23
 800 ms | thread_pool_size=10000 num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-23
 880 ms | thread_pool_size=100   num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-7
1130 ms | thread_pool_size=1000  num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-7
1120 ms | thread_pool_size=10000 num_workers=100000 loop_size=1000 affinity=0-7
```

I would suggest that you **(1) do more work in each thread; (2) use about as many threads as CPUs; (3) use a better thread pool.** Let's set `thread_pool_size` to the number of CPUs, and multiply `loop_size` by 10:

```
thread_pool version:
1880 ms | thread_pool_size=24 num_workers=100000 loop_size=10000 affinity=0-23
4100 ms | thread_pool_size=8  num_workers=100000 loop_size=10000 affinity=0-7
folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor version:
1520 ms | thread_pool_size=24 num_workers=100000 loop_size=10000 affinity=0-23
2310 ms | thread_pool_size=8  num_workers=100000 loop_size=10000 affinity=0-7
```

Notice that by increasing the amount of work per thread by 10x, we actually made the `thread_pool` version faster, and the `folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor` version only took 2x as much time. Let's multiply the `loop_size` by 10x more:

```
thread_pool version:
28695 ms | thread_pool_size=24 num_workers=100000 loop_size=100000 affinity=0-23
81600 ms | thread_pool_size=8  num_workers=100000 loop_size=100000 affinity=0-7
folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor version:
 6830 ms | thread_pool_size=24 num_workers=100000 loop_size=100000 affinity=0-23
14400 ms | thread_pool_size=8  num_workers=100000 loop_size=100000 affinity=0-7
```

For `folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor` the results speak for themselves: doing more work in each thread gets you closer to truly linear gains from parallelism. And `thread_pool` just seems not to be up to the task; it can't properly deal with this scale of mutex contention.

Here's the code I used to test (compiled with gcc 5.5, full optimization):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#define USE_FOLLY 1

#if USE_FOLLY
#include <folly/executors/CPUThreadPoolExecutor.h>
#include <folly/futures/Future.h>
#else
#include "threadpool.hpp"
#endif

int loop_size;
thread_local double dummy = 0.0;

void process(int num) {
  double x = 0;
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < loop_size; ++i) {
    x += 0.0001;
    sum += sin(x) / cos(x) + cos(x) * cos(x);
  }
  dummy += sum; // prevent optimization
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 3) {
    std::cerr << argv[0] << " [thread_pool_size] [threads] [sleep_time]"
              << std::endl;
    exit(0);
  }
  int th_count = std::atoi(argv[1]);
#if USE_FOLLY
  auto executor = std::make_unique<folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor>(th_count);
#else
  auto pool = std::make_unique<thread_pool>(th_count);
#endif
  loop_size = std::stoi(argv[3]);
  int max = std::stoi(argv[2]);

  auto then = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#if USE_FOLLY
  std::vector<folly::Future<folly::Unit>> futs;
  for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    futs.emplace_back(folly::via(executor.get()).then([i]() { process(i); }));
  }
  folly::collectAll(futs).get();
#else
  for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    pool->enqueue([i]() { process(i); });
  }
  pool = nullptr;
#endif

  int diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                 std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - then)
                 .count();
  std::cerr << "Time: " << diff << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In general, for CPU-bound code like this, you shouldn't expect any benefit from running more threads in your pool than you have cores to execute them.

For example, comparing pools with `1, 2, ... N/2 ... N ... N*2` threads for an N-core socket might be interesting. A pool with 10*N threads is really just testing how the scheduler behaves under load.

Then, also in general, you need some idea of the per-task overhead: the more tasks you split your work into, the more time is spent creating, destroying, and synchronizing access to those tasks. Varying the sub-task size for a fixed amount of work is a good way to see this.

Finally, it helps to know something about the physical architecture you're using. The NUMA server platform can do exactly twice as much work with its two sockets as the same single CPU could do alone - *if* each socket accesses *only* its own directly-attached memory. As soon as you're transferring data across the QPI, performance degrades. Bouncing a heavily-contended cacheline like your mutex across the QPI can slow the whole thing right down.

Similarly, if you have N cores and want to run N threads in your pool - do you know if they're physical cores, or hyperthreaded logical cores? If they're HT, do you know if your threads will be able to run full-speed, or will they contend for limited shared resources?

Comment: Maybe [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) is also playing a role here...